# Update a textarea value based on a dropdownlist selection

Tags: yii2

I have a dynamically loaded dropdownlist called `type_id`, and I would like that when I select a value in that dropdownlist, my `description` textarea field would be updated with a value.

**form**

```
echo $form->field($model, 'type_id')->dropDownList(ArrayHelper::map($types,'id','name'),['prompt'=>'Selecione a Área',
                'onchange' => '???']);

<?= $form->field($model, 'description')->textarea(['rows' => 8]) ?>
```

This value will be obtained dynamically through the query:

**Controller**

```
public function actionScript($id)
{
    $types = Type::find()
            ->where(['id' => $id])
            ->One();

    return $type->script;

}
```

That is, in `textarea` field I want to show the respective `script` column to the selected `id` in `type_id` dropdonw.

**type table**

```
TABLE `mod_helpdesk_type` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `priority` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `script` text NOT NULL,
  `active` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

Comment: not clear the textarea will be updated with what or which value , you dont add table schema add the model for the table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try onchange ajax event

```
echo $form->field($model, 'type_id')->dropDownList(ArrayHelper::map($types,'id','name'),[
        'prompt'=>'Selecione a Área',
        'onchange' => '
            $.get( "yourControllerName/script&id="+$(this).val(), function( data ) {
              $( "#yourTextAreaIdElement" ).val( data );
            });
        '
  ]);
```

and better prevent if request has an ids passed into actionScript

```
public function actionScript($id)
{
    $script = '';
    if(!empty($id)) {
        $types = Type::find()
            ->where(['id' => $id])
            ->one();
        if(!empty($types)) {
            $script = $types->script;   
        }
    }
    return $script;
 }
```

Comment: Perfect.
In the "yourControllerName" I had to put the complete module path: index.php? R = helpdesk / solicitation / script & id =
Thank you

Comment: yes, you need to put complete module path while pretty url not enable

Answer (score 2):

It will help you

```
    echo $form->field($model, 'type_id')->dropDownList(ArrayHelper::map($types,'id','name'),['prompt'=>'Selecione a Área',
                ['class' => 'your_class', 'id' => 'your_id']
                'onchange' => '???']);

<?= $form->field($model, 'description')->textarea(['rows' => 8,'id'=>'textArea']) ?>

$('#your_id').change(function(){
    $('#textArea').val('testing');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Like that?

```
$('#<?php echo Html::getInputId($model, 'type_id'); ?>').change(function () {
    var val = $(this).val();

    $.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo Url::to('script'); ?>',
        type: 'get',
        data: {id: val},
        success: function (data) {
            $('#<?php echo Html::getInputId($model, 'description'); ?>').val(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: You also need to fix the typo on your controller: actionScript(id): `return $type->script;` to `return $types->script;`